# Check if sum of x and x+1 numbers generates a carry at any digit (PHP)

Tags: php, math

Suppose x = 5,x = 17 and x = 91

Then,

```
5 + 6 = 11 // Carry at 10s place
17 + 18 = 35 // Carry at 10s place
91 + 92 = 183 // Carry at 100s place
```

How do I check if any number x, when added to x+1, will generate a carry at any digit.

Comment: I suppose the last example should be 91 + 92. Also, have what you tried?

Comment: Corrected it. I had tried adding the unit's digit of both numbers to see if it is <=10. But that gives the correct answer only when the carry is on the unit's place

Comment: The x=5,x=17 and x=91 was not part of the code. I would have formatted it as code if it was

Comment: Sorry mate. I'm just tensed since I am in a hurry to find a solution to this

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution you want

```
<?php
function check($number){
  $number = $number*2+1;
  return pow(10,strlen($number)-1);
}
$carry = check(995);// Change here x=5,x = 17 and x = 91
if($carry > 1){
  echo "Carry at $carry's place";
}else{
  echo "No carry forward";
}
?>
```

Check here : https://eval.in/617847

Comment: I didn't quite understand how the code will work. What should I pass at check()?

Comment: see this line `$carry = check(995);// Change here x=5,x = 17 and x = 91` pass any number for what you want to check

Comment: But if I pass check(9). It will say that the number has carry. Whereas it doesn't. Because `9+10 = 19` i.e, no carry

Comment: As you mentioned here `5 + 6 = 11 // Carry at 10s place` Is it not the same ?

Comment: Yes. It works perfectly for x=5,x=17 and x=91. But for x=9. We get `9+10=19`. So no carry. But it interprets it as carry

Comment: Could we make an algorithm to check for whether x+(x-1) would have any carry? Then we could check if `10+9` has carry as opposed to `9+10`. I think that would work

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty sloppy but you could go through every digit of each number and add them. If any of the pairs are greater than 10 you know it will have a carry.

Comment: That would be a "brute-force" solution. I thought about it. But it uses up a lot of precious RAM. Any other solution

Answer (score 0):

Do you need all of the places where there is a carry or just the highest occurrence? If it is just the highest one, I would suggest starting from the top and adding down. So, for example:

181+172 = 353 < 1000 (NO CARRY); 81+72 = 153 > 100 (CARRY), STOP.

It's a little brutish, but not quite as much as if you had to add all of the individual digits together.This is even made easier since PHP doesn't care about types, so you can use a string method on it and then use math functions.

**EDIT** PHP pseudo:

```
given x and y
while (x%10 != x && y%10 != y)
{
 pow10 = power(10, max(strlen(x), strlen(y))-1)
 if(x+y > pow10)
   print("POWER AT pow10 SPOT")

 x = x%10, y = y%10
}
```

NOTE: this only works if x and y are same length. I will leave you to figure that part out if it is necessary.

Comment: `181+172=353` It has carry on the 100s place

Comment: There is a carry in the 100s place, but not in the 10s place. But 181+172 does not cause a carry in the 1000s place. The next one, 81+72, causes the carry in the hundreds place. There is no carry in the 10s place.

Comment: Well I want to know if the addition causes any carry at all. at __any place__

Comment: Then you could just use this procedure until you hit the bottom of the stack then:

872+359 = 1231 > 1000 (CARRY); 72+59 = 131 > 100 (CARRY); 9+2 = 11 > 10 (CARRY). You just successfully detected a carry in the 1000s, 100s, and 10s spot.

Comment: I will give you PHP psuedo-code, and leave the actual syntax to you. See my adjusted answer.

Comment: Your code generates an incorrect output `444+445=889` which has __no carry__. But your code says that it __does at 100s place__

Comment: Well, then it seems that the comparison is off by a power of 10. Try not subtracting 1 in the pow() function and see if that helps. I didn't test the psuedo to see if it works. It will work if you play around with it a little bit.